# iOS Saving Images to documents directory slowing down app

Tags: file-io, ios4, documents

I am currently writing an app where I allowing a user to select images from the photos app, and add them to my app.  I find that when the users does this a couple times it is fine. The problem comes in when they do this 5-6 times, it starts to slow the app down.

I am freeing up resources, and ran it through instruments and found no leaks.  I'm just curious if there are any other things I should consider when saving images to the app this way.  I just  not seeing anything obvious at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try **FreeImage** or **OpenCV** library for reading/writing Images. Maybe they'll be more efficient than yours

Comment: It is a thought, I will look into it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read the question properly. I missed reading iOS. the libraries I mentioned are for Windows and linux. Sorry bout that

Comment: That is ok, I think I saw that open cv was ported to iOS, I was looking into that a little deeper.